# Flot labels overlapping with my line graph

Tags: jquery, flot, label, overlapping

I’m using the line graph feature of flot but I’m having some difficulty keeping my x and y-axis labels from overlapping onto the graph.  My graph looks like this

[image]

Ideally, I would like to move the labels to the left and bottom so that they don’t overlap with the graph.  I’m constructing the graph like so

```
$(function() {

<%
  js_data = []
  ids = []
  @user_my_objects.each do |user_my_object|
    ids.push( user_my_object.id )
    my_object_day_time_in_ms = user_my_object.my_object.day.strftime('%Q')
    js_data.push( "[#{my_object_day_time_in_ms}, #{user_my_object.time_in_ms}]" )
  end
%>
        // <%= ids %>
        var data = [<%=h js_data.join(",") %>];

        $("<div id='tooltip'></div>").css({
                position: "absolute",
                display: "none",
                border: "1px solid #fdd",
                padding: "2px",
                "background-color": "#fee",
                opacity: 0.80
        }).appendTo("body");

        $.plot("#placeholder", [data], {
                yaxis: {
                        tickFormatter: formatTime
                },
                xaxis: { mode: "time" },
                points: {
                        show: true
                },
                lines: {
                        show: true
                },
                grid: {
                      hoverable: true,
                      clickable: true,
                      tickColor: "#efefef",
                      borderWidth: 0,
                      borderColor: "#efefef"
                },
                tooltip: true
        });

        $("#placeholder").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
                if (item) {
                        var x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(2),
                                y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2);

                        console.log("x:" + x)
                        dateObj = new Date(parseInt(x))
                        var dateStr = $.datepicker.formatDate('MM dd, yy', dateObj)
                        $("#tooltip").html( dateStr + " - " + formatTime(y) )
                                .css({top: item.pageY+5, left: item.pageX+5})
                                .fadeIn(200);
                } else {
                        $("#tooltip").hide();
                }
        });

});
```

**Edit:** Alas the elusive Fiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/edc8jd31/1/

Comment: Try using the `margin` and `labelMargin` options under `grid`, see [here](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-grid).

Comment: So "labelMargin," right, because "margin" just seems to move everything away from teh edges of the div?  Also is there a way I can make the x-axis labels a different distance away than the y-axis labels?

Comment: Use `labelWidth` and/or `labelHeight` option for the x axis.

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to be doing anything . What about for hte y-axis?

Comment: Can you build a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that shows your chart as it is now?

Comment: I put up this fiddle but it doesn't seem to load -- I don't think its loading the external flot resources.

Comment: The missing piece of information from the question was, that you used CSS transform to style the axis labels, this was visible in the fiddle and allowed to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting form your fiddle, add `translateY(15px)` to the `transform` lines in the CSS and add `labelHeight: 30` to the `xaxis`options. See the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edc8jd31/3/) for the full example.

[image]

**Explanation:**
By using `transform: rotate(45%)` on the axis labels you rotate them around their centers which brings the left half above the axis. The additional translation moves the label below the axis. The `labelHeight` option is necessary so that the right half of the labels doesn't goes below the edge of the chart.

Answer (score 3):

Please add the following to your **CSS**:

```
#placeholder div.xAxis div.tickLabel {
    transform: rotate(0deg) !important;
    margin-top:10px;
}

#placeholder div.yAxis div.tickLabel {
    margin-right: 10px !important;
}
```

**Output:**

[image: After making change to CSS]

Comment: If Dave would not want rotated labels, why has he added the `transform: rotate()` in the first place? Just removing the styles would be better then adding another `transform: rotate(0)` ...

Comment: Hi @Raidri I'm not sure of that. And, I don't think it's the custom style he has added. I posted it assuming that it's the standard CSS of the plugin which he's using. Since he was not able to load them as an external file, he might've just paste it there. Sorry that I misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure if I understand your problem right, but you simply want to move the labels at x and z axis without moving the graph itself, right?

Maybe for the x-Axis the CSS3 property `transform: translate(x, y);` is useful for you.

And for the y-Axis you theoreticly can do the same, but for moving down margin would be better.

For a Rotation of the Labels use `transform: rotate(degrees)`

So this could maybe work:

```
#placeholder div.yAxis div.tickLabel
{
  transform: translate(-10px, 0px);
}

#placeholder div.xAxis div.tickLabel
{
  margin-top: 20px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion -- http://jsfiddle.net/edc8jd31/4/ , but the x-axis labels no longer appear slanted, as they did before.  I'd like them to still be slanted but not overwtie the graph or the y-axis labels.

Comment: Then use transform: rotate to achieve this. I updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure that I understood your problem, but are you expecting something like this ? 
Used simple jQuery to change the css of each X axis div.
jQuery :

```
$('.xAxis.x1Axis div.tickLabel').each(function() {

   var newVal = $(this).css('left');
   newVal = parseInt(newVal.substring(0, newVal.indexOf("px"))) + 15;
   $(this).css('left', newVal);

   //$(this).css('top', "492px");
   // Instead of above commented line You can use css directly.

});
```

CSS :

```
.xAxis.x1Axis .tickLabel
{
  top :492px !important;
}
```

```js
function formatTime(duration) {
  var milliseconds = parseInt((duration % 1000) / 100),
    seconds = parseInt((duration / 1000) % 60),
    minutes = parseInt((duration / (1000 * 60)) % 60),
    hours = parseInt((duration / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);

  hours = (hours < 10) ? "0" + hours : hours;
  minutes = (minutes < 10) ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
  seconds = (seconds < 10) ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

  return (hours > 0 ? hours + ":" : "") + minutes + ":" + seconds + (milliseconds > 0 ? "." + milliseconds : "");
}

$(function() {

  // [4775444, 4775496, 4775541]
  var data = [
    [1403913600000, 2915000],
    [1437782400000, 2788000],
    [1466812800000, 2759000]
  ];

  $("<div id='tooltip'></div>").css({
    position: "absolute",
    display: "none",
    border: "1px solid #fdd",
    padding: "2px",
    "background-color": "#fee",
    opacity: 0.80
  }).appendTo("body");

  $.plot("#placeholder", [data], {
    yaxis: {
      tickFormatter: formatTime
    },
    xaxis: {
      mode: "time"
    },
    points: {
      show: true
    },
    lines: {
      show: true
    },
    grid: {
      margin: 10,
      labelMargin: 5,
      labelWidth: 20,
      hoverable: true,
      clickable: true,
      tickColor: "#efefef",
      borderWidth: 0,
      borderColor: "#efefef"
    },
    tooltip: true
  });

  $("#placeholder").bind("plothover", function(event, pos, item) {
    if (item) {
      var x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(2),
        y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2);

      console.log("x:" + x)
      dateObj = new Date(parseInt(x))
      var dateStr = $.datepicker.formatDate('MM dd, yy', dateObj)
      $("#tooltip").html(dateStr + " - " + formatTime(y))
        .css({
          top: item.pageY + 5,
          left: item.pageX + 5
        })
        .fadeIn(200);
    } else {
      $("#tooltip").hide();
    }
  });

  $('.xAxis.x1Axis div.tickLabel').each(function() {

    var newVal = $(this).css('left');
    newVal = parseInt(newVal.substring(0, newVal.indexOf("px"))) + 15;
    $(this).css('left', newVal);

    //$(this).css('top', "492px");
    // instead of hardcoding you can apply via css:

  });

});
```

```css
.demo-container {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: orange;
}
#placeholder div.xAxis div.tickLabel {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  /* Firefox */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  /* Opera */
  /*rotation-point:50% 50%;*/
  /* CSS3 */
  /*rotation:270deg;*/
  /* CSS3 */
}

.xAxis.x1Axis .tickLabel
{
  top :492px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>

<div class="demo-container">
  <div id="placeholder" class="demo-placeholder" style="width:800px; height:500px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's what I want -- moving those labels so they don't overwrite each other.  However I notice to get this to work you have "$(this).css('top', "492px")".  Is there anyway to do this without hard-coding a pixel value, or maybe making it relative to sometihng?  I don't know if the graph will always be these dimensions.

Comment: @Dave Yes you can apply via css also, i just updated my code. happy coding :)